# Correct authorization-sensitive REST API

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, restful-architecture

I'm developing REST service to get the list of employees in an organization with many divisions.
If any person could get the list then API might have looked as follows:

```
GET /api/employees?filterBy=Johnson
```

But the business rules are set that require any employee to only have access to the list of his collegues in the division where he belongs.

So, Bill from **division code** 1234 will get another response to `GET /api/employees?filterBy=Johnson` than Jack from **division code** 5678. Hence, this violates idempotence of GET request.

UPDATE: ok, this doesn't violate idempotence, as Julian Reschke has noticed. I apologize for being not so accurate in terminology. Still, the problem remains regardless of the meaning of *idempotence*. Issuing two identical requests two different users generally would get two different responses. I.e. two different resources, two different views of the same data. Though GET doesn't change state of the data on the server, I believe that such scenario is a sort of misbehaviour. Maybe it would be better to say that this violates stetelessness. Or no?

Taking into account statelessness of REST API we definitely must pass that **division code** somewhere in the request. Where is that correct place? Maybe, some header like `X-SUPERCORP-DIVISION: 12345`. Or is that sufficient to suppose that **division code** can be requested from **user identity service** by authentication token, passed with original GET request? How do we manage cacheing then?

What is correct REST-ful way to build such an API?

Thank you!

Comment: You are misunderstanding the concept of "idempotence" - see RFC 7231.

Comment: @julian-reschke, would you provide any details, please? And, still, what is the correct way in this situation? (I do not mean to cite RFC 7231 here, but rather what, in your opinion, needs to be corrected in this situation.)

Comment: a) the user can be identified in many ways, HTTP auth, IP address, cookie, whatnot. putting the information into the URI or a request header field is an invitation for security problems though. b) It's no problem when GET responses vary based on request characteristics; either make it non-cacheable, or specify the cache key using the "Vary" header field.